# Can I write my whole view inside the directive as template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Can I write my whole view that has textboxes, dropdowns and labels all inside the directive as a template instead of providing a templateUrl?

I want to do this just to improve performance.

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of `templateUrl` you use `template`, where that is just a string representing your HTML. In my opinion, any performance gains you get will be offset by the loss in your own productivity b/c including anything more than one or two lines of HTML in Javascript files will get tedious.

Comment: How do you know that `templateUrl` is your biggest performance hit? I am sure that there are bigger gains to be had elsewhere in your app.